# Scala code generation with annotations + macros or external script?

Tags: scala

I want to know:

1. Can Scala annotations/transforms implement the code generation below? (objective)
2. What are the trade-offs as opposed to source code generation with an external tool? (objective)
3. Is there a better way / how would you do it? (subjective)

Background:

I'm designing an embedded database for Scala + Java as a side project. Although I want it to be usable from Java, I'm writing it in Scala for the extra flexibility/power and because writing Java code kills my soul.

I'm working out what I want model definitions to look like. My initial idea was to parse some model definition files and generate Scala classes. But I think now I'd like them to be definable in Scala code so that no parsing is required and people can bring the full power of Scala to bear in defining and customizing the models (e.g. custom column types.) That's a valuable feature from my Python/Django experience.

So far I have something like:

```
@model
class Person {
  val Name = StringColumn(length=32)
  val BirthDate = DateColumn(optional=true)
}

@model
class Student extends Person {
  val GPA = FloatColumn(propertyName="gpa")
}

@model
class Teacher extends Person {
  val salary = NumericColumn()
}
```

Which would generate:

```
class Person {
  val Name = StringColumn(name="name", length=32)
  val BirthDate = DateColumn(name="birthDate", optional=true)

  // generated accessor methods
  def name = Person.Name.get(...)
  def name_= (name : String) : Unit = Person.Name.set(..., name)
  // etc ...
}

// static access to model metadata, e.g. Person.Name is an immutable StringColumn instance
object Person extends Person

class Student extends Person {
  val GPA = DoubleColumn(name = "GPA")

  def gpa = ...
  def gpa_= (value : Float) = ...
}

object Student extends Student

class Teacher extends Person {
  // You get the idea
}

object Teacher extends Teacher
```

Looking at some examples online and doing some research, it seems like AST transforms using a special @model annotation could actually generate the needed code, maybe with a little bit of help, e.g. having the user define the object as well with the model definition. Am I right that this can be done?

Some problems that occur to me with this idea:

1. The object will be cluttered with properties that are not useful, all it needs are the Column objects. This could be fixed by splitting the class into two classes, PersonMeta and Person extends PersonMeta with Person object extending PersonMeta only.
2. IDEs will probably not pick up on the generated properties, causing them to underline them with wavy lines (eww...) and making it so auto-complete for property names won't work. The code would still be compile-time checked, so it's really just an IDE gotcha (Dynamic, no doubt, has the same problem.)

Code generation using a script is more IDE friendly, but it's hacky, probably more work, especially since you have to leave custom methods and things intact. It also requires a custom build step that you have to run whenever you change a model (which means you can forget to do it.) While the IDE might not help you with macro code generation (yet, anyway) the compiler will shout at you if you get things wrong. That makes me lean towards doing it with macros + annotation.

What do you think? I'm new to Scala, I kind of doubt I've hit on the best way to define models and generate implementations for them. How would you do it better?

Comment: Do you know about Slick? ( http://slick.typesafe.com/ )

Comment: Yes, actually I went through all the ORMs listed here to get ideas: http://manuel.bernhardt.io/2014/02/04/a-quick-tour-of-relational-database-access-with-scala/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible yeah. Macros can be unpleasant to write and debug, but they do work.

1. Seems like you already have your solution there
2. Scala IDEs tend to handle macros correctly-ish (I mean, they have to, they're part of the language and used in some pretty fundamental libraries), so I wouldn't worry about that; if anything a macro is more ide-friendly than an external codegen step because a macro will stay in sync with a user's changes.

I'd see whether you can achieve what you want in vanilla scala before resorting to a macro. Remember that your class-like things don't necessarily have to be actual case classes; take a look at [Shapeless generic records](https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless/wiki/Feature-overview:-shapeless-2.0.0#extensible-records) for an idea of how you can represent a well-typed "row" of named values from somewhere external. I think a system that could map a structure like those records to and from SQL might end up being more principled (that is, easier to reason about) than one based on "special" case classes.

Comment: 2) gives me hope. I found [this](http://blog.jetbrains.com/scala/2014/01/23/heading-to-the-perfect-scala-code-analysis/#comment-2877) from the beginning of 2014, saying that JetBrains is working on macro support. I didn't find any updates on the progress (or non-progress) towards that goal. But it still seems the way to go. I think it can be done with vanilla Scala as well, but with a higher runtime cost. The great part is with code generation the accessor methods compile down to a simple mov instruction when inlined by the JIT. Performance is a main goal, and it doesn't get better than that